# Sharepoint site publicly searchable in google

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to know if a sharepoint site created on Office365 is publicly searchable in google or not? and how can I change this privacy then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not searchable on google. No privacy can be configured to show it on google.